# Show that $f(x) = D(x+1)$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that $f(x)=D(x+1)$ is L- measurable , where $D$- Dirichlet function .
$
D(x) =\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{if } x \not\in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$, 
$f(x) = D(x+1)$ 
 Function is measurable when $A_{a}=\{x \in X : f(x)<a  \} $ . So let consider 3 cases : 
  $a \in (-\infty,0]$,  $a \in (0,1]$ and $a \in (1,+\infty)$

Case 1 : $A_{a} = \emptyset \in L$,
Case 2 : $A_{a} = \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \in L$
Case 3: $A_{a} = \mathbb{R} \in L$ 
But i think that something is wrong, i considered 3 same cases as for the Dirichlet function . How to modify it ?

Comment: Don't you mean Function is measurable when $A_a \in L $ ? Besides, shouldn't one case cover having both $0,1$ in $A_a$?

Comment: @gary . Yes  i mean that function is measurable when $A_{a} \in L $.  Right. What gives $D(x+1) ? $ . is that a translation for $D(x) $? . Maybe have you better way to describe this ?

Comment: :As someone comented below, the translation does not change the measurability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 4 cases here : Your open set $U$ contains neither zero nor 1, exactly one of them, or both:
Let $A_a:=D^{-1}(U)$ We need $A_a$ to be Lebesgue -measurable

1) Contains neither .
Then $A_a$ = Empty

2) $U$ contains $0$ but not $1$
 Then $A_a=\mathbb R -\mathbb Q $, which is measurable ( $G_{\delta}$)

3) $U$ contains $1$ but not $0$.
Then $A_a = \mathbb Q$ , which is measurable ( by #3, taking complement)

4) $U$ contains both $0,1$
 Then $A_a = \mathbb R $ , which is of course measurable.

This is another argument: $D(x)$ is measurable and $T(x):=x+1$ is continuous. Then $D(x+1)=D(x) \circ T(x) $, so that, for $U$ open in $\mathbb R $ : $$ D(x+1)^{-1}(U) $$

Is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to modify it at all, $x \in \mathbb{Q} \iff x+1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ so the preimages of $D$ are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do it in this way: $D(x+1)=\chi_{\bf{Q}}(x+1)=\chi_{{\bf{Q}}-\{1\}}(x)=\chi_{\bf{Q}}(x)=D(x)$, where ${\bf{Q}}-\{1\}=\{x-1: x\in{\bf{Q}}\}={\bf{Q}}$.

Comment: Now i understand , this is the way i see .